# Devise "current_user" method in CanCan ability results with "undefined method"  error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, devise

I'm trying to use Devise authorisation with CanCan roles in my rails3+mongoid app.
Now I have to limit users access to edit the events, so only their author could do this. Author of the event is determined by that line:

```
    <%= f.hidden_field (:author, :value =>current_user.email) %>
```

So, now in CanCan's Ability file i'm trying to use this code:

```
  class Ability  
  include CanCan::Ability 

  def initialize(user)  
    user ||= User.new    
    if user.role? :admin  
      can :manage, :all  
    else 
        can :read, :all  
      end
      if
        user.role?(:normal)
        can :create, Event  
        can :update, Event do |event|  
          event.try(:author) == current_user.email
      end 
        can :create, Comment  
        can :update, Comment do |comment|  
        comment.try(:author) == current_user.email 
      end 
    end 
  end
```

end

But this results me with this error:

> undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #

Then i've tried to change

```
can :update, Event do |event|  
          event.try(:author) == current_user.email
```

to

```
event.try(:author) == Devise.current_user.email
```

but that results with this error

> undefined method `current_user' for Devise:Module

So, what should I do and how can I call for `current_user' method from ability.rb? Thank you in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you referring to `current_user` in your initialize method? Why not just the `user` that was supplied as an argument to the method?

CanCan will call initialize for the current_user when it needs to.